# How do I enforce an ASP.NET Web API Filter on a per-route basis?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that inherits `HttpSelfHostConfiguration`, where I do the following:

```
this.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new ControllerTypeResolverByNamespace("Web.Controllers"));

this.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

This sets up controllers within the `Web.Controllers` namespace, so then I can do, for example:

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class TestController
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("api/test")]
        public Boolean Test()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

There are different routes within these controllers. I am wanting to implement a filter per route, so for example, only for the `api/test` route in the `Web.Controllers` namespace.

I've created an attribute class:

```
public class TestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.RequestContext.ClientCertificate != null)
        {
            return base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
        else
        {
            return actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to enable that filter for all requests, this is correct?

```
this.Filters.Add(new TestAttribute());
this.Services.Replace(typeof (IHttpControllerTypeResolver), new ControllerTypeResolverByNamespace("Web.Controllers"));
this.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

How can I enable that attribute per route? Everything I've come across is in regards to different .NET frameworks, i.e. ASP.NET Core, or they show very little code and expect you to just understand. I am new to .NET in general, and this codebase I am working on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's probably an attribute you can apply to the routes you want that does this?

Comment: *"How can I enable that attribute per route?"* -  your `[HttpGet]` and `[Route]` **are attributes**, you can put your own attribute that way. i do curious, your `TestAttribute` looks like enforcing HTTPS but have you met [`[RequireHttps]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requirehttpsattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) thing?

Comment: oh right, get a decent IDE (e.g. Visual Studio) that has IntelliSense. it will help you a lot. if you could have ReSharper it could teach you new tricks.

Comment: @BagusTesa I actually have both VS and Rider installed. For some reason they both don't highlight errors-- I think it's to do with the number of projects and files in this codebase that they're stuck trying to index. That's a separate issue though :P. So, essentially, add [Test] (or is it [TestAttribute]?) to the route. Nothing needs to be done in the server configuration side?

Comment: either way is fine, the `Attribute` suffix can be omitted by convention, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes).